# Node-RED read Serial status

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi3

My flow have 1 input node (Serial).

Phisically, in this Serial, I can connect difference type of device (printer, keyboard ecc...).

When I connect a device in the serial port, Node-RED recognize it and switch the node status from "not-connected" to "connected".

There is any way to obtain this status (connected/not connected) in a variable to use it?

I have try to check "msg.status" variable but there is no information inside...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it!

Just use the "status" node in the input table and configure it.